# Show that partial derivative with respect to time is anti-hermitian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, hilbert-space

I have a definition that $$<s_1,s_2> = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}s_1^*(t)s_2(t) dt$$

I need to show that $\partial_t$ operator which is just the partial derivative with respect to time is anti-hermitian.

I.e $$<s_1,\partial_ts_2> = - <\partial_t s_1, s_2>$$

After doing integration by parts I get:
$$<s_1,\partial_t s_2> = - \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} s_2 \partial_t s_1,$$ but I need the last integral to be in the form: $-\int _{-\infty}^{+\infty} \partial_ts_1 s_2 $ i.e I just need to swap the $s_1$ and $s_2$ around. Is there any way I can do this? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think that you need to "swap them around", they are just complex numbers, they commute!

Comment: So you are saying that $<s_1,s_2> = <s_2,s_1>$?

Comment: @VaibhavSharma no, he's saying $\bar{s}_1(x)s_2(x)=s_2(x)\bar{s}_1(x)$...that is quite different from $\bar{s}_1(x)s_2(x)=\bar{s}_2(x)s_1(x)$